# Enviar um array de objetos em um ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, json

Estou com a seguinte dúvida neste código.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
                <th>Cpf</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Marque</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="list in listaDeAlunos" >
            <tr>
                <td>{{list.cpf}}</td>
                <td>{{list.nome}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{list.cpf}}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Eu quero guardar em um array no controller pelo ng-click todos os alunos(todos seus dados) selecionados pelo checkbox, que estão nessa table. É possível isso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `ng-model` para mapear diretamente a avaliação do estado de um `checkbox`. Exemplo funcional a seguir, clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd>:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("testController", function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.marcados = {};

        $scope.listaDeAlunos = [
            { cpf:'111', nome: 'Aaa' },
            { cpf:'222', nome: 'Bbb' },
            { cpf:'333', nome: 'Ccc' },
            { cpf:'444', nome: 'Ddd' },
        ];
        
    $scope.$watch('marcados', function(){
    
      angular.forEach($scope.marcados, function(v,k) {
        if (!v) delete $scope.marcados[k];
      });
    
    }, true);
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="testController">
    
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-info table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
                <th>Cpf</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Marque</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="list in listaDeAlunos" >
            <tr>
                <td>{{list.cpf}}</td>
                <td>{{list.nome}}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="marcados[list.cpf]" ng-true-value="{{list}}", ng-false-value="null"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<pre>{{marcados | json}}</pre>

    </body>
```

Comment: Legal cara, e eu consigo passar o nome também do aluno ? A ideia do meu projeto é enviar os alunos selecionados dos check box pra uma outra tabela. Tem um array dentro do controller, chamado alunos selecionados. E eu tenho um botão que chamaria uma função através do ng-click ,pra enviar esses alunos selecionados, pra dentro desse array de alunos selecionados la na função do controller. Isso seria possível? Passar o objeto inteiro ?

Comment: Olhe o código
 <tbody ng-repeat="alunos in listaDeAlunos" >
      <tr>
         <td>{{alunos.cpf}}</td>
          <td>{{alunos.nome}}</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="marcados[alunos]"></td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>

<li>
       <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="tooltip"  
              title="Envia os alunos selecionados para a tabela do lado" 
              ng-click="enviarAlunos(alunos)">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
       </button>
</li>

Comment: @VagnerBellaver Eu alterei o exemplo para preservar o objeto completo.

Comment: Obrigado. Eu vou estudar o código. Perdoe-me se parece meio leigo. Estou iniciando no angular em minhas aulas de Construção de Páginas de Web 4, e gostei muito do angular, devido sua praticidade.  Por isso tento entender o código. 
No seu exemplo você trata os checkbox, em tempo de execução. É possível passar todos dentro de uma diretiva ng-click ?

Comment: @VagnerBellaver Sem problema algum, somos todos newbies em algum momento! No exemplo acima eu estou utilizando o comportamento nativo do Angular para povoar o objeto `marcados`. Entretanto você pode passar a referência do objeto atual para um método via `ng-click='metodo(list);'`, onde `list` é o item da coleção `listaDeAlunos`.

Comment: Se eu selecionar vários checkbox e mandar o list no ng-click todos os objetos que eu selecionei, irão para a função ? Se eu entendi direito.

Comment: @VagnerBellaver Quase isso. Se você adicionar o ng-click ao elemento checkbox que está sendo repetido, o evento será disparado *para cada clique*. Neste momento você pode gerenciar uma lista.

Comment: Comecei a entender. Cada checkbox que eu seleciono, ele chamaria a função. Lá na funcão, ele recebe o objeto e é só dar um array.push, ou seria necessário fazer alguma verificação?
Como ficou aqui.
<td>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="marcados[alunos.cpf]"
                         ng-true-value="{{alunos}}" ng-false-value="null"
                           ng-click="enviarDados(alunos)" >
</td>

Comment: @VagnerBellaver um click pode ser para desativar o check. Neste caso você precisa remover o item.

Comment: Então lá na função teria que ter uma verificação de Checked ?

Comment: @VagnerBellaver http://stackoverflow.com/a/20290803/1845714

Comment: Consegui alcançar meu objetivo @OnoSendai. Esse vídeo foi a luz no fim do tunel
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExgtvARcBXE
Agradeço muito à você. De muito valor foi sua ajuda.
Grande abraço.

Comment: @VagnerBellaver Sempre um prazer ajudar, e fico feliz que tenha conseguido botar pra funcionar!

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

HTML:

```
ng-click="guardaObjs(list)"
```

"Chame a função dentro do loop"

Controller:

`guardaObjs(obj){
//aqui vc manipula o array (obj)
}`

Comment: <tbody ng-repeat="list in listaDeAlunos" >
                <tr>
                    <td>{{list.cpf}}</td>
                    <td>{{list.nome}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="'{{list}}'"></td>
                </tr>
Dessa forma ele ira mandar somente os Checkboxes selecionados, ou terá que colocar um checked em algum momento ?